# How do I set my GPU's fan curve when using Nouveau?

Tags: linux, drivers, gpu, nouveau, fan

I accidentally ended up using the Nouveau driver (as opposed to the proprietary NVIDIA driver) for my GPU today and was surprised by how well it worked. I am aware of the reclocking issue (that is, that the clock speeds are stuck low). Regardless, I'm considering switching to primarily using it, but I have one significant issue preventing me from doing so: my GPU's fans. When using Nouveau they constantly spin at almost 2000 RPM despite the card not being particularly warm (according to lm-sensors) and as a result are very loud. I would like to set the fan curve to something more reasonable. How might I do this in Linux when using the Nouveau GPU driver?

Worth noting is that I have a GTX 970 which according to this matrix has support for controlling the fan speed: https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/PowerManagement.html (edit: never mind, the GTX 970 is one generation too new to support this due to firmware issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/nouveau#Fan_control

As for the fan curve, `man fancontrol` :

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fan_speed_control#Fancontrol_(lm-sensors)

Comment: `fancontrol` in my experience works horribly but then I last tried it over a decade ago. If I were you, I'd use binary NVIDIA drivers anyways - nouveau might be quite unstable and lead to frequent system crashes. If it's stable for you, then it's OK to use it.